# Getting ajax based data in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, search

I try to make a finder (kind of advanced search), I came half way and i'm facing issue by getting third part of my search query.

## Logic

1. Select category
2. Select Subcategory
3. Select Specifications of products in Subcategory
4. Select Brands in Subcategory

[image: screen1]

Basically user will select category, then select subcategory of that category `till here I've done` then all specifications and brands of that subcategory products will be presented to select.

## issue

> My problem is to get specifications and brands from selected
>   subcategory.

Reason that I want to get these info base on chosen subcategory is because each subcategory products have different brand and specifications for example i don't want to show `cpu` specification while user chooses `mouse` subcategory! there is no cpu for any kind of mouses, that's the whole reason.

## codes

`blade`

```
<form action="" class="mt-20">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="category_id">category</label>
                    <select name="category_id" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Select Category</option>
                        @foreach($findercategories as $category)
                            <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->title}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div><!-- end col-md-3 -->
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="subcategory_id">subcategory</label>
                    <select name="subcategory_id" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Select Subcategory</option>
                    </select>
                </div><!-- end col-md-3 -->
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="specification_id">specifications</label>
                    <select name="specification_id" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Select Specification</option>
                    </select>
                </div><!-- end col-md-3 -->
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="brand_id">brands</label>
                    <select name="brand_id" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Select Brand</option>
                    </select>
                </div><!-- end col-md-3 -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-9">
                        <button style="margin: 20px;" class="pull-right btn btn-info" type="submit">Find</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </form>
```

`Javascript`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="category_id"]').on('change', function() {
      var categoryID = $(this).val();
      if(categoryID) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url('getSubCategories') }}/'+encodeURI(categoryID),
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data) {
        $('select[name="subcategory_id"]').empty();
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            $('select[name="subcategory_id"]').append('<option class="form-control" value="'+ value['id'] +'">'+ value['title'] +'</option>');
            });
        }
      });
      }else{
        $('select[name="subcategory_id"]').empty();
      }
    });
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="subcategory_id"]').on('change', function() {
      var subcategoryID = $(this).val();
      if(subcategoryID) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url('getspecifications') }}/'+encodeURI(subcategoryID),
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data) {
        $('select[name="specification_id"]').empty();
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            $('select[name="specification_id"]').append('<option class="form-control" value="'+ value['id'] +'">'+ value['title'] +'</option>');
            });
        }
      });
      }else{
        $('select[name="specification_id"]').empty();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

`controller`

```
//get categories list
$findercategories = Category::ofStatus('Active')->get();

//finder (subcategories)
    public function getSubCategories($id){
        $subcategory = Subcategory::where('category_id', $id)->get();
        return response()->json($subcategory);
    }

//finder (specifications + brands)
    public function getspecifications($id){
        $product = Product::where('subcategory_id', $id)->get();
        $productsubsp = DB::table('product_subspecification')->where('product_id', $product)->get();
        $specifications = $productsubsp;
        return response()->json($specifications);
    }
```

`routes`

```
Route::get('/getSubCategories/{id}', 'frontend\SearchController@getSubCategories');
Route::get('/getspecifications/{id}', 'frontend\SearchController@getspecifications');
```

## Extra (just to be clear about data i try to get)

1. My product brands are saving with id in `products` table in column
   named `brand_id`
2. My product specifications are saving in third table named
   `product_subspecification` which will get `id` `product_id` and
   `subspecification_id`

This is how i get those info in front-end:

for brands

> {{$product->brand->title}}

and for specifications

in controller

```
$specifications = $product->subspecifications->mapToGroups(function ($item, $key) {
        return [$item->specification->title => $item];
    });
```

in blade

```
@foreach($specifications as $specificationtitle => $specificationcollection)
<tr>
<th style="width:150px;">{{ $specificationtitle }}</th>
<td class="text-left">
@foreach($specificationcollection as $subspecification)
{{$subspecification->title}}
@endforeach
</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

This returns like:

> CPU  CORE I5 CORE I3 CORE I7
>
> RAM  2 GIG 4 GIG

## UPDATE

I managed to get my result in specifications dropdown, however i have problem with getting all my products under chosen subcategory `I only can get last product` and not all of them.

## codes

here is how i get my results currently

```
public function getspecifications($id){
            //find products under subcategory
             $product = DB::table('products')
                            ->where('subcategory_id', $id)
                            ->get();
                            foreach($product as $pp) {
                            }
            $specificationsw = $pp->id; //get products id (currently has issue, only gets 1)

            // find products specification with same product id
            $specificationss = DB::table('product_subspecification')
                            ->where('product_id', $specificationsw)->get();
                            foreach($specificationss as $dd) {
                            }
            $specificationsss = $dd->subspecification_id; //get specifications id from product_subspecification table


            // get specifications title base on table above
           $specifications = DB::table('subspecifications')
                            ->where('id', $specificationsss)->get();
        return response()->json($specifications);
    }
```

any idea how to get all my products `id` instead of only last one `which i'm getting currently`?

## UPDATE2

I changed my controller to code below and now i'm able to get all my products from subcategory:

```
public function getspecifications($id){
            //find products under subcategory
            $product = DB::table('products')
                            ->where('subcategory_id', $id)
                            ->get();
            $date = array();
            foreach ($product as $stan) {
                $date[] = $stan->id;
            }
            $specificationsw = $date; //get products id (currently has issue, only gets 1)

            // find products specification with same product id
            $specificationss = DB::table('product_subspecification')
                            ->where('product_id', $specificationsw)->get();
            $date2 = array();
            foreach ($specificationss as $stan2) {
                $date2[] = $stan2->subspecification_id;
            }
            $specificationsss = $date2; //get specifications id from product_subspecification table

            // get specifications title base on table above
            $specifications = DB::table('subspecifications')
                            ->where('id', $specificationsss)->get();
            $date3 = array();
            foreach ($specifications as $stan3) {
                $date3[] = $stan3;
            }           
            $specifications = $date3;
        return response()->json($specifications);
    }
```

now here is my `dd` results:

`dd($specificationsw);` products dd which is id of products `2 products`

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => 27
  1 => 38
]
```

`dd($specificationsss);` product_subspecification table result `only return values of product id 27. nothing for product id 38!`

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => 5
  1 => 8
]
```

`dd($specifications);` result of last part of my function `i get this title in my ajax code in front-end` but as you see info about `subspesification` id `8` and `product` id `38` is lost.

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => {#722 ▼
    +"id": 5
    +"title": "4 GIG"
    +"specification_id": 2
    +"created_at": "2017-12-04 00:00:00"
    +"updated_at": "2017-12-04 00:00:00"
  }
]
```

Comment: Suddenly, right at the end of the question we of learn something involving `<th><\th>` and `<td><\td>`. Why?

Comment: no thats from my product view just to show how i return specifications. is not included my problem. as i said Extra (just to be clear about data i try to get)

Comment: If it's not relevant to the problem, I suggest leaving it out otherwise people like me will be confused.

Comment: i think it is relevant because i try to get exact same data in my finder, so people know what I&#39;m looking to achieve, but if i see it cause issues later i might take your suggestion and remove it. anyway do you have idea how to solve my issue?

Comment: Ok, good luck with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLVED

I solved my issue here is for those in need:

**Explanation:**

1. first method of controller will get subcategories base on chosen
   category id.
2. second method will show `specifications` base on selected subcategory, `note` in my case specifications where stored in their table and related to my products with [sync method](http://www.tjd-studio.com/blog/article/how-to-use-sync-method-in-laravel) in third table. (will show specifications that used in products under that subcategory only)
3. third method will show `brands` base on selected subcategory (will show brands that used in products under that subcategory only)

`Controller` methods

```
//finder (find subcategories base on selected category)
    public function getSubCategories($id){
        $subcategory = Subcategory::where('category_id', $id)->get();
        return response()->json($subcategory);
    }

    //finder (show specifications base on selected subcategory)
    public function getspecifications($id){
            $specifications = DB::table('products')
                        ->where('subcategory_id', $id)
                        ->join('product_subspecification', 'product_subspecification.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
                        ->join('subspecifications', 'subspecifications.id', '=', 'product_subspecification.subspecification_id')
                        ->groupBy('subspecifications.id')
                        ->get();
            return response()->json($specifications);
    }

    //finder (show brands base on selected subcategory)
    public function getbrands($id){
        $specifications = DB::table('products')
                    ->where('subcategory_id', $id)
                    ->join('brands', 'brands.id', '=', 'products.brand_id')
                    ->groupBy('brand_id')
                    ->get();
                    return response()->json($specifications);
    }
```

> **Important:** In order to avoid duplicated results in `specifications` and `brands` I used `groupBy`.

`Routes`

```
Route::get('/getSubCategories/{id}', 'frontend\SearchController@getSubCategories');
Route::get('/getspecifications/{id}', 'frontend\SearchController@getspecifications');
Route::get('/getbrands/{id}', 'frontend\SearchController@getbrands');
```

`Scripts`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="category_id"]').on('change', function() {
      var categoryID = $(this).val();
      if(categoryID) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url('getSubCategories') }}/'+encodeURI(categoryID),
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data) {
        $('select[name="subcategory_id"]').empty();
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            $('select[name="subcategory_id"]').append('<option class="form-control" value="'+ value['id'] +'">'+ value['title'] +'</option>');
            });
        }
      });
      }else{
        $('select[name="subcategory_id"]').empty();
      }
    });
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="subcategory_id"]').on('change', function() {
      var subcategoryID = $(this).val();
      if(subcategoryID) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url('getspecifications') }}/'+encodeURI(subcategoryID),
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data) {
        $('select[name="specification_id"]').empty();
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            $('select[name="specification_id"]').append(
                  "<option class='form-control' value='"+ value['id'] +"'>"+ value['title'] +"</option>"
                  );
            });
        }
      });
      }else{
        $('select[name="specification_id"]').empty();
      }
    });
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="subcategory_id"]').on('change', function() {
      var subcategoryID = $(this).val();
      if(subcategoryID) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url('getbrands') }}/'+encodeURI(subcategoryID),
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data) {
        $('select[name="brand_id"]').empty();
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            $('select[name="brand_id"]').append('<option class="form-control" value="'+ value['id'] +'">'+ value['title'] +'</option>');
            });
        }
      });
      }else{
        $('select[name="brand_id"]').empty();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```